# How to grep out a batch of consecutive lines from a file

Tags: grep

I want to grep out a batch of consecutive lines, that starts at a specific pattern and ends at specific pattern. 
E.g. the content of file looks like this :

line 1

line 2

.
.
.

my_start_pattern

.
.
.

my_end_pattern

.
.
.

line n

The output of grep should look like following :

my_start_pattern

.
.
.

my_end_pattern

Thanks.

Comment: Why `grep`? This doesn't seem like the right tool for the job.

Comment: Grep will display N lines after and/or before a match (N being a number) but will not display lines between two matches.  Take a look at the awk utility.

Comment: Other tool is okay, it's just to me this seems like a grepping issue, i could be wrong. I'm looking at awk, but so far haven't been able to achieve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if grep can do this, but awk can.

```
awk '/start pattern/,/end pattern/' data_file_name
```

(leave off the file name if you want to filter from stdin)

Comment: I came by this answer and I was wondering if there is a way to modify this `awk` command to trim off the `start pattern` and `end pattern` from the output.

Comment: Off the top of my head: `awk '/start pattern/,/end pattern/ { if (!/start pattern/ && !/end pattern) print }' data_file_name`

Comment: Knew there had to be some short ways to do this and did a quick search and found [Print lines using ranges](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/#awk_ranges)